# How to create multiple contexts for the same Adobe Air ANE extension

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air

Is there a way to create multiple instances of the same ANE extension using multiple contexts?

I have read the documentation and it says that I can, but I cannot understand how.

At the moment if I try to create a new instance of the extension, the data that I return gets mixed up (data from one instance is returned to the other one).

Here is the iOS initialiser that I have:

```
FREObject init(FREContext ctx, void* funcData, uint32_t argc, FREObject argv[])
{
    eventContext = ctx;

    return NULL;
}
```

Maybe the problem is that every time I call the `init` method from ActionScript, the context is just set to the latest one by the method?

I have also read http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/extending-air.html, which points to the scenario I want - a one-to-one relation between the extension and the new context that I create. The problem there is that I return data from the ANE to AS by sending an empty `FREByteArray` object from AS which is then filled with data - I am not dealing with contexts, so I cannot distinguish them at this step.

Any guidance will be very helpful, as I might not understand the concept of the contexts and misuse them.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using contextType?

In Obj-C

```
typedef void (*FREContextInitializer)( 
    void*                        extData, 
    const uint8_t*           contextType, 
    FREContext               context, 
    uint32_t*                numFunctionsToSet, 
    const FRENamedFunction** functionsToSet
);
```

In ActionScript

```
ExtensionContext.createExtensionContext(EXTENSION_ID, CONTEXT_TYPE)
```

References:

[FREContextInitializer() Native C](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/extensions/WSb464b1207c184b14-62b8e11f12937b86be4-7ffd.html)

[ExtensionContext.createExtensionContext() ActionScript](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExtensionContext.html#createExtensionContext())

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Would context type make any difference, since I am not reading it and I do not have different methods depending on the context type?

Comment: well you can use it as if condition in your FREContextInitializer

Comment: `void YourContextInitializer (void* ctxData, const uint8_t* ctxType, FREContext ctx, uint32_t* numFuncToTest, const FRENamedFunction** funcToset)
{
    
*numFuncToTest = 1;

FRENamedFunction* func = (FRENamedFunction*)malloc(sizeof(FRENamedFunction) * (*numFuncToTest));
    
    
func[0].name = (const uint8_t*)"init";

func[0].functionData = NULL;
    if([[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) ctxType] isEqual @"demo"])
    {
           func[0].function = &initOne;
    } else
    {
          func[0].function = &initTwo;
    }
    *funcToset = func;
}`